# Increment date by one day to a set epoch date

Tags: javascript

I would like to increment a (epoch) date by one day.

So far I have:

```
let date = "1535162451650"; // August 24 2018
console.log(new Date(parseInt(date, 10)).getDate() + 1);
```

This spits out `25` so I am on the right track. How would I convert it back to a Date object?

This is going to be in this map function:

```
return data.map(t => ({
  id: t.id,
  start_date: new Date(parseInt(t.date_created, 10)),
  duration: // here, taking the above start date and adding one day
  )
}));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Looks ugly but seems to work

```
let date = "1535162451650";
console.log(new Date (new Date(parseInt(date, 10)).setDate(new Date(parseInt(date, 10)).getDate() + 1)));
// gives me aug 25 2018
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? haha

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add day in milliseconds to achieve this.

```
let date = "1535162451650"; // August 24 2018
console.log(new Date(parseInt(date, 10)).getDate() + 1);

let nextDay = +date + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 1 day in millisecond

nextDay = new Date(nextDay)
console.log(nextDay)
```

You can also use `momentjs` in following way:

```
var date = 1535162451650

date = moment(abc)
console.log('date', date.format('DD MM YYYY'))

date = date.add(1, 'day')
console.log('date', date.format('DD MM YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
var options = {
  id: t.id,
  start_date: new Date(parseInt(t.date_created, 10))
};
options.duration = new Date(options.start_date.getTime());
options.duration.setDate(options.duration.getDate() + 1);
return data.map(t => (options));
```